# How to indicate to the server that a REST HTTP call is asynch?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

Just read about HTTP response code 202, where a POST returns no body and instead returns a location to poll (getting 200s) until completion (getting a 201 or 303).

In C#, we communicate this by the convention of giving a method an Asynch suffix to the method name (and it returns a task or takes a call back reference).

How do I communicate this in HTTP? Do I invent my own ad hoc method, or is there some request header or other standard means for for indicating this?

And is there a standard way to tell the client how often to poll? (And as I understand HTTP, there isn't a way to do a call back without polling, right?)

I have read this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079367/use-http-status-202-for-asynchronous-operations), it does not address how a client distinguishes between an synch vs an asych request, nor how to communicate polling rates. Ditto for this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388923/rest-responsive-ui-for-slow-operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I communicate this in HTTP? Do I invent my own ad hoc method,
>   or is there some request header or other standard means for for
>   indicating this?

I believe the 202 accepted is mostly used by eventual consistency. Afaik there is no standard way to describe a poll link, so you have to use your ad-hoc solution. By HTTP you can poll only, but you can use websockets in combination with HTTP if you don't want your clients to poll. (note: websockets is not REST)

You can possibly use an already existing [vocab to describe a poll link](http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/search?q=poll) with linked data. I haven't found a vocab, which contains this term, so I am afraid you have to define it in your own vocab or probably with a custom link relation... :S

Answer (score 0):

From [Firefox manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/bar/foo.txt", true); // True is asynchronous
xhr.onload = function (e) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
     if (xhr.status === 200) {
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
    console.error(xhr.statusText);
  }
 }
};
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
  console.error(xhr.statusText);
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is telling the XMLHttpRequest client to behave in an asynchronous manner, but the server will behave the same as always. (i.e. the request in fiddler would be identical if the param is true or false)